# Is there a way to have filter condition applied to only one column without effecting result set of other column

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I need a result set from multiple tables , I need to apply filter on one of the table column without effecting the result set of other column. below is the query i have tried.

```
               SELECT  
               AGG.PROMO_RUN_KEY,
               AGG.CUSTOMER_KEY,
               AGG.TEST_CUSTOMER_CODE,
                PRM.STORE_KEY,
               PRM.STORE_CODE,                 
               PRM.PRODUCT_KEY,
               PRM.PRODUCT_CODE,
               PRM.CUSTOMER_CODE,
               PRM.CUSTOMER_CODE_TY,
              AGG.PROMOTION_KEY,
        FROM aggr AGG
          JOIN RUN DP ON DP.PROMO_RUN_KEY = AGG.PROMO_RUN_KEY
          left join (select  
           PRM.STORE_KEY,
   PRM.STORE_CODE,
   PRM.PROMOTION_CODE,
   PRM.COMM_CHANNEL_KEY,
    PRM.PRODUCT_KEY,
   PRM.PRODUCT_CODE,
   PRM.CUSTOMER_CODE,
   PRM.CUSTOMER_CODE_TY,
   PRM.PROMO_RUN_KEY, prm.customer_key,REDEEM_CUSTOMER_CODE,                 
   from  cust PRM
    join aggr AGG
   on AGG.PROMO_RUN_KEY = PRM.PROMO_RUN_KEY
    AND AGG.CUSTOMER_KEY = PRM.CUSTOMER_KEY
    JOIN STORE DS ON PRM.STORE_KEY = DS.STORE_KEY
    JOIN PRODUCT DPR ON PRM.PRODUCT_KEY = DPR.PRODUCT_KEY
        WHERE   ds.ORG_CODE IN ('#store_bu#')) and dpr.att1 in ('x','Y')
       ) prm
    ON AGG.PROMO_RUN_KEY = PRM.PROMO_RUN_KEY
    AND AGG.CUSTOMER_KEY = PRM.CUSTOMER_KEY
```

in the given query when i apply filter in prm subquery my count of AGG.TEST_CUSTOMER_CODE this should not change
only count of PRM.CUSTOMER_CODE_TY should varry.

Comment: Just to get more understanding, "you want to apply filter on a column and don't want to change the record count", is it?

Comment: record count of one of the derived column  from agg (agg.test_customer_code)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide some sample data, the results that you are getting and the results that you want to achieve. However, in their absence, you might try a COUNT DISTINCT on the AGG columns or possibly do the counts of AGG and PRM in separate CTEs and then bring the 2 resultsets together in a final SQL statement - however this may well give duplicate rows and therefore risk double counting if you further query that final resultset